# Convert serialized data from the database into a PHP array

Tags: php, json

I've got some custom data inputted into the postmeta table for each of my WooCommerce orders.

```
a:2:{i:6517;a:2:{i:0;a:5:{s:10:"first_name";s:5:"Roger";s:9:"last_name";s:6:"Rabbit";s:5:"email";s:19:"roger@benefacto.org";s:7:"is_lead";b:1;s:12:"is_cancelled";b:0;}i:1;a:5:{s:10:"first_name";s:7:"Jessica";s:9:"last_name";s:6:"Rabbit";s:5:"email";s:21:"Jessica@benefacto.org";s:7:"is_lead";b:0;s:12:"is_cancelled";b:0;}}i:6518;a:2:{i:0;a:5:{s:10:"first_name";s:6:"Mickey";s:9:"last_name";s:5:"Mouse";s:5:"email";s:20:"mickey@benefacto.org";s:7:"is_lead";b:0;s:12:"is_cancelled";b:0;}i:1;a:5:{s:10:"first_name";s:6:"Donald";s:9:"last_name";s:4:"Duck";s:5:"email";s:20:"donald@benefacto.org";s:7:"is_lead";b:0;s:12:"is_cancelled";b:0;}}}
```

-- EDIT ---

I initially assumed this was encoded with JSON, but following the answers below understand it is actually serialized data.

I want to convert this data into a PHP array - something like below - so I can play with it.

```
 $data = array ( 
    '6517' => array ( 
        0 => array ( 
            'first_name' => 'Roger',
            'last_name' => 'Rabit',
            'email' => 'roger@benefacto.org',
            'is_lead' => 1,
            'is_cancelled' => 0,
        ),
        1 => array (
            'first_name' => 'Jessica',
            'last_name' => 'Rabit',
            'email' => 'jessica@benefacto.org',
            'is_lead' => 0,
            'is_cancelled' => 0,
        )
    ),
    '6518' => array (
        0 => array (
            'first_name' => 'Mickey',
            'last_name' => 'Mouse',
            'email' => 'mickey@benefacto.org',
            'is_lead' => 1,
            'is_cancelled' => 0,
        ),
        1 => array (
            'first_name' => 'Donald',
            'last_name' => 'Duck',
            'email' => 'donald@benefacto.org',
            'is_lead' => 0,
            'is_cancelled' => 0,
        )
    )
);
```

Any thoughts much appreciated!

Comment: this is not json format, you have to create your own parser, or check php unserialize function http://php.net/manual/it/function.unserialize.php

Comment: Use `unserialize`

Comment: That's not JSON, it's PHP's `serialize` format. http://php.net/unserialize

Comment: Thanks all - that works very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments above this data is serialized rather than JSON encoded. For anyone else reading, the following works well.

```
// Pull serialized data 
$serializeddata = 'a:2:{i:6517;a:2:{i:0;a:5:{s:10:"first_name";s:5:"Roger";s:9:"last_name";s:6:"Rabbit";s:5:"email";s:19:"roger@benefacto.org";s:7:"is_lead";b:1;s:12:"is_cancelled";b:0;}i:1;a:5:{s:10:"first_name";s:7:"Jessica";s:9:"last_name";s:6:"Rabbit";s:5:"email";s:21:"Jessica@benefacto.org";s:7:"is_lead";b:0;s:12:"is_cancelled";b:0;}}i:6518;a:2:{i:0;a:5:{s:10:"first_name";s:6:"Mickey";s:9:"last_name";s:5:"Mouse";s:5:"email";s:20:"mickey@benefacto.org";s:7:"is_lead";b:0;s:12:"is_cancelled";b:0;}i:1;a:5:{s:10:"first_name";s:6:"Donald";s:9:"last_name";s:4:"Duck";s:5:"email";s:20:"donald@benefacto.org";s:7:"is_lead";b:0;s:12:"is_cancelled";b:0;}}}';

// Unserialize it into a standard array
$array = unserialize($serializeddata);

// Print Array
print_r($array);
```